# Transactional tests with spring boot and hibernate jpa repository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, transactional

I want to write transactional unit test so changes will be rolled back when method is finished, but I'm faced with problem because of using hibernate and JPA repositories. For some reasones i get UnsupportedOperationException when trying annotate @Test method with @Transactional 
Here a code where I'm trying to test orphan removal logic, everything is ok, but I dont want these entities in database after method is finished.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class NotificationGroupServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  private NotificationGroupService notificationGroupService;

  private NotificationGroupEntity groupEntity;
  private Long groupId;
  private NotificationCriterionEntity notificationCriterionEntity;
  private HistoricalNotificationEntity historicalNotificationEntity;

  @Before
  public void initializeEntities() {
    groupEntity = new NotificationGroupEntity();

    groupEntity = notificationGroupService.createOrUpdate(groupEntity);
    groupId = groupEntity.getId();

    notificationCriterionEntity = new NotificationCriterionEntity();
    historicalNotificationEntity = new HistoricalNotificationEntity();
    notificationCriterionEntity.setNotificationGroupId(groupId);
    historicalNotificationEntity.setNotificationGroupId(groupId);
    groupEntity.setHistoricalNotifications(Arrays.asList(historicalNotificationEntity));
    groupEntity.setActiveNotificationsList(Arrays.asList(notificationCriterionEntity));
  }

  @Test
  public void testOrphanRemoval() {
    notificationGroupService.createOrUpdate(groupEntity);

    Optional<NotificationGroupEntity> optionalNotificationGroupEntity =
        notificationGroupService.findById(groupId);

    Assert.assertTrue(optionalNotificationGroupEntity.isPresent());

    groupEntity = optionalNotificationGroupEntity.get();

    Assert.assertEquals(1, groupEntity.getActiveNotificationsList()
        .size());
    Assert.assertEquals(1, groupEntity.getHistoricalNotifications()
        .size());
    Assert.assertEquals(groupEntity.getActiveNotificationsList()
        .get(0)
        .getNotificationGroupId(), groupId);
    Assert.assertEquals(groupEntity.getHistoricalNotifications()
        .get(0)
        .getNotificationGroupId(), groupId);

    groupEntity.setActiveNotificationsList(Arrays.asList());
    groupEntity.setHistoricalNotifications(Arrays.asList());

    notificationGroupService.createOrUpdate(groupEntity);

    optionalNotificationGroupEntity =
        notificationGroupService.findById(groupId);

    Assert.assertTrue(optionalNotificationGroupEntity.isPresent());

    groupEntity = optionalNotificationGroupEntity.get();

    Assert.assertEquals(0, groupEntity.getActiveNotificationsList()
        .size());
    Assert.assertEquals(0, groupEntity.getHistoricalNotifications()
        .size());
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@After` annotation to indicate the method(s) to be run after every `@Test`.

The full suite of annotations like this are:

- `@BeforeClass` - before all `@Tests` are run
- `@Before` - before each `@Test` is run
- `@After` - after each `@Test` is run
- `@AfterClass` - after all `@Tests` are run

If you are asking how to associate a particular teardown method to a particular @Test method, there is no need for annotations: Simply call it at the end of your test method in a finally.

And your test class should be :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:/spring-beans.xml")
public class NotificationGroupServiceTest {
....
}
```